# K-Nearest Neighbors OpenCV algorithm

Tags: java, opencv, evaluation, knn

I'm using OpenCV 2.4.12

```
predictedValues = knn.find_nearest(samples, k, results, neighborResponses, dists);
```

This line basically gets the result of knn. Now my problem is how to evaluate the result?Is there any function that i can use?Otherwise do i need to compare the `predicted` with the `results` Mat?

[Documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/ml/doc/k_nearest_neighbors.html)

Thanks

Ps.Thanks to guneykayim, i need to add a few peaces of code to make my question more clear. I have more than 1 vector

```
Mat predicted = new Mat(results.rows(), 1, CvType.CV_32F);
float predictedValue;
for (int i = 0; i < testData.rows(); i++)
{
        final Mat samples = testData.row(i);
        //predicted.<Float>at(i,0) = knn.find_nearest(samples, k);
        predictedValue = knn.find_nearest(samples, k, results, neighborResponses, dists); //TODO: wie mat dists aufsetzen-10?
        predicted.put(i, 1, predictedValue);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The documentation, which you shared, says:

> If only a single input vector is passed, all output matrices are
>   optional and the predicted value is returned by the method.

So, if your `samples` object has multiple vectors, your results are returned with the `results` object, and you don't need `predictedValues` object. However if your input is just a vector, then you don't need `results` object, you can use the functions return value, which is `predictedValues` in your case.

**P.S.** The function returns **only one** `float` value, not multiple values.